Euler's formula with a different derivation by Welch Labs
I'm an electrical engineer and I have seen
a Welch Labs video:
The most beautiful equation in math, explained visually [Euler’s Formula]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f8CXG7dS-D0
In this vido they derive Euler's formula (without Taylor series).
At 09.30 time point of this lecture we can see that  $2^{bi}$ and $2^{-bi}$ unknown functions are conjugate of each other.
Can  anybody help me to understand how I can conclude this from the previous facts in this video ??
This would be the key condition that these values { $2^{bi}$ and $2^{-bi}$ }  are on the circle of unit radius as I see .
E.g: a finite polynomial with real coefficients $P_n(bi)$ and $P_n(-bi)$ are conjugate pairs because of the relationship between four basic operations and conjugation.
But in this case at this moment in the video the function of power of 2 is unknown so
I can't see why { $2^{bi}$ and $2^{-bi}$ } are conjugate pairs ?

a few things..  $2$   is real and positive, so any $2^z$  with complex $z$  is defined. Next,   $e^z$  is defined by a power series  with all real coefficients. In particular,  for real $t,$  we have $e^{it}  =  \cos t + i \sin t.$  Also $e^{s+it}  = e^s \cdot (  \cos t + i \sin t).$    and $2^z = e^{z \log 2}$ where $\log 2$  is real.  I guess that I should emphasize  $e^{s-it}  = e^s \cdot (  \cos t - i \sin t)$   really is the complex conjugate of $e^{s+it}$

This flaw in the video has a comment about it with 148 upvotes.

@MarkS Where can I find  this comment?

@WillJagy My question is related to the video. We cannot use Euler's formula because it is Euler's formula that will be proven in the video. pls. see the first 9 minutes.

This is a genuine gap in the video's argument. Shortly after the video was posted, YouTube user "F & Yu", posted a comment on the video (which has 148 likes at the time of writing this answer) stating:

9:33 You define a conjugate as "flipping the sign of the imaginary component" but what you're doing here is not flipping the sign of the imaginary component, but flipping the sign of the exponent, which happens to be imaginary. Of course in reality it amounts to the same thing, but that's what we're trying to prove! We don't know yet if 2^(-bi) is the conjugate, so we can't use this fact to prove the magnitude of our number is 1.

A reply comment from YouTube user Sven Kja points out that assuming that $2^{-i}=\left(2^i\right)^{-1}$ combined with the "exponents add" rule the video assumes, can get us the result. They write (converted to TeX by me):

Correct. However.
If $2^i=a+bi$, we have
$2^{-i}=\dfrac1{a+bi}$
$=\dfrac{a-bi}{a^2+b^2}$
$=c(a-bi)\text{.}$
Imposing $2^i \cdot 2^{-i} = 2^0 = 1$, we obtain $c=1$ and we have shown $2^{-i}=a-bi$.


Thanks for the detailed answer, I would be glad if I could see an elementary proof e.g: without the Taylor series.
Unfortunately as I see you can't conclude in your derivation that $c=1$ because you can't use the assumption $\mid(2^i)\mid=\mid(2^{-i})\mid$ so $c=\frac{1}{(a^2+b^2)}$.
From $2^i*2^{-i}=1$ we can conclude only $\mid(2^{-i})\mid=\frac{1}{\mid(2^i)\mid}$ and $arc(2^{-i})=-arc(2^i)$ e.g.:if we are thinking in polar coordinates.
Can you advise anything?
